# Symfony add csrf token check for other pages

Tags: php, symfony, security, csrf

Official documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html) of symfony states, to user CSRF protection I should add

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            # ...
            form_login:
                # ...
                enable_csrf: true
```

It works only for login form. This article (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html#csrf-protection-in-symfony-forms) says, that I can user method **isCsrfTokenValid** in the controller to check the token. I have another page, not, login page, where I want to check csrf token. Can you configure it somehow in the security.yaml or isCsrfTokenValid is the only way?

Comment: What do you mean by, it only works in the login form? The doc page is a bit confusing, so maybe you accidentally use different token-ids? In the FormType in docs the token id is `task_item`, then the twig.template use s`delete-item`, and in the controller they use `delete-item` again. If you always use the same id the validation should work. Can you explain what is not working? Does it not show the token in the rendered page? Is it not part of the submitted data in your controller? Does validation fail?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated that "form_login" refers to built in functionality. "enable_csrf: true" is a parameter of that functionality and doesn't work for any thing else. So for all other forms I have to use isCsrfTokenValid